# Call TIBCO BW6 process from Java code

Tags: tibco-business-works

I'm looking for a way to automate testing for our TIBCO BW6 applications.

There are 2 test methods I would like to use: Unit tests and BDD.

For unit testing I would like to be able to call a subprocess with some in- and output, and assert the processed data.

For BDD I would like to use Cucumber, and test the entire flows from start to end.

To accomplish this, it would be nice if I could call (sub)processes from Java with some in- and output.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Tibco BW6 process/subprocess  are defined by BPEL language. So, I think it is possible de call a process from Java client. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/integrate.1012/b14448/invoke.htm can help

Answer (score 0):

Since in tibco bw 6 the paradigm is to have every process build as a soap/rest service, you may call these processes from java called the same way you would call a soap/rest service. 
In case you have a subprocess implemented without a binding you may easily refactor this and test it from java code.

Answer (score 0):

The BW 6.4.0 release introduced Unit Testing within BW6!

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.4.0/relnotes/GUID-10ED9A26-AED6-4A2D-B274-2E7A558DC98D.html

> "You can now take the Test-Driven Design(TDD) approach for developing
>   ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks applications with the new Unit Testing
>   feature. You can define assertions for individual activities in the
>   BusinessWorks Process, test the assertions through the debugger and
>   see the test results in the Debug perpsective. Refer to Unit Testing
>   in the Application Development guide."

BW6 (6.4.2) Unit Testing Documentation : 
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.4.2/doc/html/GUID-20758669-A9B4-4D84-95DB-0BFDA225E068.html